# Symfony2 - How to validate autocomplete entity form type?

Tags: php, jquery, validation, symfony, symfony-validator

I have a form with following fields:

```
$builder
    ->add('title', 'text')
    ->add('body', 'textarea')
    ->add('tags', 'entity', [
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tag',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => true,
    ]);
```

User can select multiple tags. Everything works perfectly. But now when the numbers of tag become very large (over 20000 tags), page rendering become very slow because entity type loads all tag into selectbox. Therefore I implement a jQuery autocomplete selectbox to prevent loading all entity but when I submit the form, validator still loads all tags to validate! How can I solve this validation issue? Thank you!

Comment: the only chance you have is to implement your own field type with your own validation. you could also restrict the amount of tags by using the `query_builder` option, provided it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `entity` field type, use simple `text` type that will accept ID of the associated entity. You also need to make data transformer to transform submitted ID to entity object (and vice versa) that will be set on the form's data entity.

[Data transformer example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#harder-example-transforming-an-issue-number-into-an-issue-entity)

Validation will work as if it was `entity` field type, thanks to the data transformer.